# Swap images with animation or delay on JS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, settimeout

I've fond a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/17g6q8k0/2/

```
    <img data-alt-src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png"
src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cancel.png" />
```

and JS part

```
        var sourceSwap = function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
            $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', newSource);
        }

        $(function() {
            $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
                new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
            }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
        });
```

When you move mouse on image it's changing. When you remove mouse - it's changing back as it was.

In current example it changes momentally.

How to add pause or animate it (animation better)?

This images have same size. But i'll use it with images which have differ sizes (like [f] and [facebook] buttons on mousehover) and to make it more easy for eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your script a bit http://jsfiddle.net/17g6q8k0/182/

You'll need to use css anyway. The first option is to create div with background and animate it.

However, there is another way if you want to use < img>. You have to create container with 2 images.

```
<div class="hover-image">
  <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cancel.png"/>  
  <img class="hover" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png"/>
</div>
```

One of it must be positioned absolute and lay over the first image.

```
.hover-image .hover {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Than you can animate opacity of these two images.

```
$this.find("img").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("hover")) {
    $(this).animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, "slow");
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      'opacity': 0
    }, "slow")
  }
});
```

Comment: It is great! But is it possible to put them all in one line?
All 3 images in 1 line instead of new line for each?

Comment: @nikitasius, yes, just remove clear:both; from css container http://jsfiddle.net/17g6q8k0/210/

Comment: great, but when i've added differ images (smaller changes in bigger), it gives problems:  http://jsfiddle.net/17g6q8k0/212/

Comment: @nikitasius, you can calculate container width http://jsfiddle.net/17g6q8k0/213/ - see comments in JS block

Comment: but they have empty space between them.
The idea is:  use small icons for space economy. And when use move mouse he'll see full text image. Icons should be sticked together in default state.

Comment: @nikitasius, when user hovers icon, the big icon must overlay all other icons?

Comment: no. It should be between them (if it in the middle).
Like this:

[f][t][in]  -> [facebook][t][in]

[f][t][in]  -> [f][twitter][in]

[f][t][in]  -> [f][t][instagram]


User see big icon when his mouse still on it and see small around. When there is no cursor on images - only small icons, sticked together.

If big icon will overlay all another, user not will be able to select icons around.

Comment: murdad, just a question: is it possible to improve this JS? In current way: when image changed and you move mouse to another - another start to change when previous not go back yet. Is it possible to do some kind of queue? Previous picture goes back and only after this another can change?

Comment: @nikitasius, yes, you can do this. But in this case, it's better to create a javascript class. If you want, I can help you with it

Comment: It will be nice! Want me to create new question on stackover?

Comment: @nikitasius yes, please. That would be useful for thou, who would like to create a jQuery animation queue

Answer (score 1):

I know what you are trying to do, but don't. Image substitution is a technique from 10-15 years ago. If you want to animate a checkmark to a cancel sign, the best way would be to morph an SVG object. There is a whole library that can do this for you:
http://www.transformicons.com/

They even have a check > cancel sign object. The code for just that one object looks like this...

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="tcon tcon-remove tcon-remove--check" aria-label="remove item">
  <span class="tcon-visuallyhidden">remove item</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.tcon {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  .tcon > * {
    display: block; }
  .tcon:hover,
  .tcon:focus {
    outline: none; }
  .tcon::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0; }

.tcon-remove {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
  transform: scale(0.75);
  width: 40px; }
  .tcon-remove::before,
  .tcon-remove::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37%;
    left: 8%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background: black; }
  .tcon-remove::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); }
  .tcon-remove::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg); }

.tcon-remove--check.tcon-transform::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(5%, -10%);
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(5%, -10%);
  top: 50%;
  width: 55%; }

.tcon-remove--check.tcon-transform::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20%, 10%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20%, 10%);
  top: 50%;
  width: 85%; }

.tcon-visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px; }
  .tcon-visuallyhidden:active,
  .tcon-visuallyhidden:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto; }
```

JS:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD module
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS-like environment (i.e. Node)
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser global
    root.transformicons = factory();
  }
}(this || window, function () {

  // ####################
  // MODULE TRANSFORMICON
  // ####################
  'use strict';

  var
    tcon = {}, // static class
    _transformClass = 'tcon-transform',

    // const
    DEFAULT_EVENTS = {
      transform : ['click'],
      revert : ['click']
    };

  // ##############
  // private methods
  // ##############

  /**
  * Normalize a selector string, a single DOM element or an array of elements into an array of DOM elements.
  * @private
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements
  * @returns {array} Array of DOM elements
  */
  var getElementList = function (elements) {
    if (typeof elements === 'string') {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(elements));
    } else if (typeof elements === 'undefined' || elements instanceof Array) {
      return elements;
    } else {
      return [elements];
    }
  };

  /**
  * Normalize a string with eventnames separated by spaces or an array of eventnames into an array of eventnames.
  * @private
  *
  * @param {(string|array)} elements - String with eventnames separated by spaces or array of eventnames
  * @returns {array} Array of eventnames
  */
  var getEventList = function (events) {
    if (typeof events === 'string') {
      return events.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    } else {
      return events;
    }
  };

  /**
  * Attach or remove transformicon events to one or more elements.
  * @private
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be toggled
  * @param {object} [events] - An Object containing one or more special event definitions
  * @param {boolean} [remove=false] - Defines wether the listeners should be added (default) or removed.
  */
  var setListeners = function (elements, events, remove) {
    var
      method = (remove ? 'remove' : 'add') + 'EventListener',
      elementList = getElementList(elements),
      currentElement = elementList.length,
      eventLists = {};

    // get events or use defaults
    for (var prop in DEFAULT_EVENTS) {
      eventLists[prop] = (events && events[prop]) ? getEventList(events[prop]) : DEFAULT_EVENTS[prop];
    }

    // add or remove all events for all occasions to all elements
    while(currentElement--) {
      for (var occasion in eventLists) {
        var currentEvent = eventLists[occasion].length;
        while(currentEvent--) {
          elementList[currentElement][method](eventLists[occasion][currentEvent], handleEvent);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  /**
  * Event handler for transform events.
  * @private
  *
  * @param {object} event - event object
  */
  var handleEvent = function (event) {
    tcon.toggle(event.currentTarget);
  };

  // ##############
  // public methods
  // ##############

  /**
  * Add transformicon behavior to one or more elements.
  * @public
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be toggled
  * @param {object} [events] - An Object containing one or more special event definitions
  * @param {(string|array)} [events.transform] - One or more events that trigger the transform. Can be an Array or string with events seperated by space.
  * @param {(string|array)} [events.revert] - One or more events that trigger the reversion. Can be an Array or string with events seperated by space.
  * @returns {transformicon} transformicon instance for chaining
  */
  tcon.add = function (elements, events) {
    setListeners(elements, events);
    return tcon;
  };

  /**
  * Remove transformicon behavior from one or more elements.
  * @public
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be toggled
  * @param {object} [events] - An Object containing one or more special event definitions
  * @param {(string|array)} [events.transform] - One or more events that trigger the transform. Can be an Array or string with events seperated by space.
  * @param {(string|array)} [events.revert] - One or more events that trigger the reversion. Can be an Array or string with events seperated by space.
  * @returns {transformicon} transformicon instance for chaining
  */
  tcon.remove = function (elements, events) {
    setListeners(elements, events, true);
    return tcon;
  };

  /**
  * Put one or more elements in the transformed state.
  * @public
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be transformed
  * @returns {transformicon} transformicon instance for chaining
  */
  tcon.transform = function (elements) {
    getElementList(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.add(_transformClass);
    });
    return tcon;
  };

  /**
  * Revert one or more elements to the original state.
  * @public
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be reverted
  * @returns {transformicon} transformicon instance for chaining
  */
  tcon.revert = function (elements) {
    getElementList(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove(_transformClass);
    });
    return tcon;
  };

  /**
  * Toggles one or more elements between transformed and original state.
  * @public
  *
  * @param {(string|element|array)} elements - Selector, DOM element or Array of DOM elements to be toggled
  * @returns {transformicon} transformicon instance for chaining
  */
  tcon.toggle = function (elements) {
    getElementList(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      tcon[element.classList.contains(_transformClass) ? 'revert' : 'transform'](element);
    });
    return tcon;
  };

  return tcon;
}));
```

Comment: I need to animate social buttons. Checkmarks just an example from fiddle what i've fond in google.
User have small icons (twitter, facebook etc) and when he move mouse on it he see large icon. And because of differ sizes it seems crazy and too fast and sharp for eyes. So i need to make it slower.

Comment: You still shouldnt use images + JS. Use an icon font and manipulate the size of the branded icon with CSS. Font Awesome has a brand section of icons that are unbelievably easy to implement: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand

Comment: FA gives only an icon "f" for facebook. I need simple solution icon with "f" and another with "facebook" when user move his mouse on "f".

Comment: Yeah, then you are right - you will need to do image substitution on it. You should talk with your design lead and see if they will back off that requirement. You'd be much better off using an icon font or the SVG method above.